# Debug Assertion Failed String subscript out of range

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, hash, assertion

So I wrote a simple Hash class, and when using the visual studio environment I get a debug assertion error "Expression: String subscript out of range" However when I use c++ Linker on the command prompt to compile and run the program runs fine. The error occurs at h.add("a", "la");

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
bool die(const string &msg);

class Hash{
    public:
        Hash( unsigned tablesize, unsigned maxUsed );
        ~Hash();
        bool in( const string & code ) const;
        bool getDescription( string & description, const string & code ) const;
        void add( const string & code, const string & description );
        void changeDescription( const string & code, const string & newDescription );
        void showone(const string &code) const;
        void show() const;
    private:
        struct Data{
            string code;
            string descrip;
        };
        unsigned hash(unsigned val) const;
        unsigned rehash(unsigned val) const;
        static unsigned Hash::partialHash( const string & code );
        static bool prime( unsigned n );
        unsigned findindex(const string &code) const;
        Data *ptr;
        unsigned maxUsed;
        unsigned elements;
        unsigned tablesize;
        unsigned p;
        unsigned p2;
};

Hash::Hash(unsigned size, unsigned maxused){
    if(UINT_MAX-3<size || size<=4 || size<=maxused )
        die("Invalid Constructor");
    for(tablesize=size; !prime(tablesize); tablesize++){}
    ptr=new Data[tablesize];
    elements=0;
    maxUsed=maxused;
    for(p=tablesize; !prime(--p);){}
    for(p2=p; !prime(--p2);){}
    for(unsigned i=0; i<tablesize; i++){
        ptr[i].code="\0";
        ptr[i].descrip="\0";
    }
}

Hash::~Hash(){
    delete[] ptr;
}

bool Hash::in(const string &code)const{
    if(code==ptr[findindex(code)].code)
        return true;
    return false;
}

void Hash::showone(const string &code) const{
 unsigned i=findindex(code);
 cout<<'['<<i<<"]: "<<ptr[i].code<<' '<<ptr[i].descrip<<'\n';
}
void Hash::show() const{
 for(unsigned i=0; i<tablesize; i++)
  cout<<'['<<i<<"]: "<<ptr[i].code<<' '<<ptr[i].descrip<<'\n';
}

bool Hash::getDescription( string & description, const string & code ) const{
    if(in(code)){
        description=ptr[findindex(code)].descrip;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void Hash::changeDescription(const string & code, const string & newdescription ){
    if(in(code)){
        ptr[findindex(code)].descrip=newdescription;
    }else{
        die("code not in table");
    }
}

unsigned Hash::hash(unsigned partialHashValue)const{
    return partialHashValue%p;
}

unsigned Hash::rehash(unsigned partialHashValue)const{
    return partialHashValue%p2+1;
}

unsigned Hash::partialHash( const string & code ){
    return (code[0]*26+code[1])*26+code[2];
}

void Hash::add( const string & code, const string & description ){
    if(in(code)) die("can't add");
    if(elements==maxUsed) die("Overflow");
    unsigned i=findindex(code);
    ptr[i].code=code;
    ptr[i].descrip=description;
    elements++;
}

bool Hash::prime( unsigned n ){
        if( n < 4 )  return n > 1;
        if( n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0 )  return false;
        for(  unsigned fac = 5, inc = 4;  ;  fac += inc = 6-inc  ){
            if( fac > n/fac )  return true;
            if( n%fac == 0 )  return false;
        }   
    }

unsigned Hash::findindex( const string &code) const{
    unsigned partial=partialHash(code);
    unsigned hashnum = hash(partial);
    if(ptr[hashnum].code=="\0" || ptr[hashnum].code == code) return hashnum;
    unsigned rehashnum = rehash(partial);
    do{
        hashnum = (hashnum + rehashnum) % tablesize;
    }while(  ptr[hashnum].code != "\0" && ptr[hashnum].code != code );
    return hashnum;
}

int main(){
    Hash h(12, 8);
    h.add("LAX", "Space Shuttle Endeavour arrived here 9/21/2012");
    h.add("DEN", "jajaja");
    h.add("gold", "lalalala");
    h.add("Pp", "la");
    h.add("a", "la");
    h.add("b", "la");
    h.add("c", "la");
    h.add("d", "la");
    cout<<"p\n";
    h.showone("LAX");
    cout<<"\n\n";
    h.show();
}

bool die(string const &msg){
 cerr<<"fatal error: "<<msg;
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Here is teh output

```
[0]: gold lalalala
[1]: DEN jajaja
[2]: LAX Space Shuttle Endeavour arrived here 9/21/2012
[3]:
[4]:
[5]: a la
[6]: b la
[7]: Pp la
[8]:
[9]: d la
[10]: c la
[11]:
[12]:
```

Comment: The assertion means that you are using an out-of-bound index.  When it occurs, the debugger should break, giving you the opportunity to observe the state of your program and figure out what you are doing wrong.  The assertion is a utility for debugging and is only raised when iterator debugging is enabled (which it is likely not in your command line build).  "Here's my program; it's broken; please debug it for me" is really not appropriate form for a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Without checking the code note that when using the debugger it checks for a lot more things that won't be noticed on the command line. You could be corrupting memory, unlikely with just reading, but you could be reading rubbish, but you don't notice in a simple program like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In partialHash funciton, code[2] is out-of-boundary access when code only contains "a"

```
unsigned Hash::partialHash( const string & code ){
    return (code[0]*26+code[1])*26+code[2];
}
```

you could use at() function and catch the thrown exception

```
   unsigned Hash::partialHash( const string & code )
    {
        try {
          return (code.at(0)*26+code.at(1))*26+code.at(2);
        } 
        catch(std::exception& e){
          std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: aaahhhh that makes sense. Seems like I need to make sure the string is 2 letters or more for my hash, right? Why is it working outside of the  visual studio environment?

Comment: It's undefined behavior to access out-of-boundry memory, you are lucky if it doesn't crash in other environment or not lucky as it doesn't tell the bug directly.

Comment: I see that makes more sense. Thanks for your help I really appreciate it.